# Matrix of list or something similar

Tags: r, matrix

I am working with matrices but I need a more complex matrix for my study. In my case, each element in the matrix have to have different information fields. I have been reading about but I don't find anything such as vector a of struct in C/C++.

So my question is the following:

Is it that possible in R? Something like a matrix of lists or a dataframe of lists.

Thank you in advance and best regards!

Comment: You could certainly make a list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a matrix of list elements, for example

```
mat = matrix(list(), 3, 4)
```

or

```
mat = vector("list", 12)
dim(mat) = c(3, 4)
```

The elements of such matrix can be accessed like elements of a list:

```
mat[[1,2]] = c(1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Andrey! It is exactly what I am looking for.